# Server Error - Access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2012

I've got this error when I run my web app in my visual studio 2012. This happens after I've changed the web config to windows authentication mode.

These are the lines of codes I've changed from the original web config.

```
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="true" />
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
```

Actually, when I deployed this project to the web server, it works perfectly fine. Now, my problem is that I could not debug this project using the visual studio 2012 cuz I have this error. I've tried opening other project and it works using the visual studio and mine is not but these two have same set-up.

[image]

Comment: In your `%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` look for `<applicationPoolDefaults>`. Under `<processModel>`, make sure you don't have `setProfileEnvironment="false"`. If you do, set it to true.

Comment: It is set to true already.

Comment: The website is working when i access this url [http:\\phpet-web05:8008]

Comment: My problem is when I debug my code using visual studio, when I try it that error displayed.

Comment: Never mind !! check this setting  `1. Open iis and select the website that is causing the Issue
2. Open the “Authentication” property under the “IIS” header
3. Click the “Windows Authentication” item and click “Providers”
4. Move NTLM at top`

Comment: It can't see Providers when I click the windows authentication. It is only enable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91811/discussion-between-webruster-and-bum).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, in your project properties, you can choose which type of server you want. You must choose "IIS Server" and "Create virtual directory" to be in the same configuration as your deployment server and be able to set all needed parameters.
You'll certainly need to open IIS manually (outside of VS) to configure security settings on your development WebSite.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following:

1. Go to IIS Server, Click on Web site you created and look for Windows 
   Authentication, It should not be disabled
2. Check the folder were you kept you code and look try to give the full 
   permission to the current AD user.
3. Alternatively, you can try creating the .html page in you home directly and try 
   browsing the page.